# OpenSSH-Server in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, authentication

Problem connecting to server

I can ping the server (Ubuntu  server 16.04 no GUI) and the server can ping the desktop (Ubuntu 18.04).
I have installled Openssh-server 7.6p1 on the desktop machine.
The server installation has no GUI and the Openssh version is
There is an ethernet adapter that plugs into  a server USB. No cable just a transceiver that is enabled
that communicates with the wifi router.
So far so good, but if I ssh the server as follows it defaults to the client everytime.

```
root@xxxdesktop:/home/andycc# ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa  root@xxxserver.ubuntuhome.net -v -p
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to xxxserver.xxxhome.net [x.x.x.7] port nn
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to xxxserver.xxxhome.net:54219 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:5Irn4Yn4FkYwxAouW41TYIWe9duri4WoOdFjd2Sk51o
debug1: checking without port identifier
debug1: Host 'xxxserver.xxxhome.net' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug1: found matching key w/out port
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:ZwS+vr6fZV5+uA36BIAwA0h7lYwrK7K4mrpscSx+7rE /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xxxserver.ubuntuhome.net (x.x.x.7]:54219).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-99-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

 * Canonical Livepatch is available for installation.
   - Reduce system reboots and improve kernel security. Activate at:
     https://ubuntu.com/livepatch

5 packages can be updated.
5 updates are security updates.

Last login: Mon May 11 21:06:41 2020 from 192.168.0.4
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have set the ownership and permissions on the client and the server as follows:

```
root@vostro230desktop:~# 
home/androo/.ssh $ chown androo:androo -R home/androo/.ssh (server)
home/androo/.ssh $ chmod 600 * 
home/androo $ chmod 700 .ssh

root@xxxdesktop:/home/androo# ls -al .ssh
drwx------  2 androo androo 4096 May 10 13:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 androo androo 4096 May 10 20:59 ..
-rw-------  1 androo androo 1628 May 10 13:02 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 androo androo 1679 May 10 15:52 id_rsa
-rw-------  1 androo androo  403 May  10 15:52 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------  1 androo androo 2870 May 10 20:40 known_hosts
-rw-------  1 androo androo  617 May  11 01:29 known_hosts.old
```

similarly I have set permissions on the root directory  on both the client and the server as follows

```
root/.ssh $ chown root:root -R root/.ssh
root/.ssh $ chmod 600  *
root/ $ chmod 700 .ssh
```

here is the client setup of ownership and permission which is identical to the server configuration aprart from the user name.

```
home/andycc/.ssh $ chown andycc:andycc -R home/andycc/.ssh (client)
home/andycc/.ssh $ chmod 600 * 
home/andcc $ chmod 700 .ssh

root@xxxdesktop:/home/andycc# ls -al .ssh
drwx------  2 andycc andycc 4096 May 10 13:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 andycc andycc 4096 May 11 20:59 ..
-rw-------  1 andycc andycc 1628 May 10 13:02 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 andycc andycc 1679 May  8 15:52 id_rsa
-rw-------  1 andycc andycc  403 May  8 15:52 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------  1 andycc andycc 2870 May 11 20:40 known_hosts
-rw-------  1 andycc andycc  617 May  8 01:29 known_hosts.old
```

The etc/ssh/ssh_config  file options on the Ubuntu 18.04  desktop client are as follows:

```
Host x.x.x.x
CheckHostIP yes
StrictHostKeyChecking no
IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa
Port 54xxx
Protocol 2
PasswordAuthentication no
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

the sshd_config file options for the server are as follows:

```
port 54nnn
protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key           
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Use PrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3800
ServerKeyBits 1024
SyslogFacility AUTH
Loglevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin without-password
StrictModes yes
AllowUsers andyccc
RSAAuthentication no
PubKeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile root.ssh/authorized_keys
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
Accept LANG 
Subsystem stp/usr/lib/…
UsePAM yes
```

Comment: Is `xxxserver.ubuntuhome.net` on the same LAN as `xxxdesktop`? How is `xxxserver.ubuntuhome.net` resolved, and are `[x.x.x.7] port nn` the expected IP address and port? Aside from the `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS` string, what is the evidence that *"it defaults to the client"*?

Comment: A philosophical question; if your source node is a Desktop and the destination node is a server, why did you install OpenSSH server on the Desktop (as opposite to the client: openssh-client)?

Comment: That's a very reasonable question. Why did I install OpenSSH-server on the workstation if there is already OpenSSH-server on the server. As I understand it you cannot just install the client. It comes with the Server installation or not at all. I may be wrong about this but it might also be at the root of my problem.

Comment: @steeldriver I still have the problem of it defaulting to the client installation and I checked this by looking at the hostname in /etc. This is particularly difficult to solve as I don't think many people have experienced this problem. Any ideas? and thanks

Comment: @AndrewCarlile are you able to answer any of my other questions?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for the reply. Sure, and apologies; I neglected to answer the questions you posed. Both machines are on the same LAN with no other nodes apart from the router which is wired into the Desktop via an ethernet cable. The xxxserver.ubuntuhome.net is, I believe, resolved by the /etc/hosts file. The x.x.x.7  is the resulting IP address  and nn the port number. I did at first try to change the port number. I used ufw allow and the port no. nn/tcp. I  also used  ufw allow ssh, none of which resolved my original problem . Thanks for looking into this for me.

Comment: @steeldriver Hi again, I have still omitted to answer one of your questions. 'are [x.x.x.7} and port nn the expected IP address and port?'  Yes they are.  Thanks again.